# How to add paragraph spacing for the first paragraph of the page

Tags: microsoft-word

Doing this kind of
[space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCihy.png)

does not work for the first paragraph of the page.

Comment: Note, I edited my response to add screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You must not be sharing some other context here because I don't understand what you are saying is a problem of assigning **spaces before** the first paragraph on a page. Below is an example that I just tested. I've turned on the Option to show text boundaries so you can see it.

[image]

Another option if you don't want to directly assign it by placing your cursor insertion point in the first paragraph, right-clicking, and then opening the Paragraph Formatting dialog, would be to create a custom paragraph style with the **Spaces Before at 36 pts** and applying that style to the first paragraph only.

And I suppose a third option is to set the first as its own Section and then adjust the Top Margin down some distance on the page.

Comment: You cannot adjust the margins of just the first page of a section.

Comment: Yes, you can as long as Section 1 is just one page in length.

Answer (score -1):

Space before paragraph spacing, by itself, does not work at the top of a page unless the page is the first in a Section.

### You can use a Frame as part of the style definition for the paragraph.

Then the space-before setting will work regardless of where the paragraph is in the document. I've illustrated this in [my page on Frames and Text Boxes](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#SpaceBefore).

### A second option is to insert a Next-Page or Odd/Even-Page Section Break.

In my opinion the frame solution is preferable because of the baggage carried by section breaks.

### From [my page on Frames](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#SpaceBefore):

In recent versions of Word, Frames are required to provide space before the heading starting a new chapter after a page break or a column break. (Note: this is a problem with a page break or a column break, but not a page break inserted as part of a Section break.)

By design, Word ignores the space setting for the paragraph without the Frame. The same thing happens with a column break. Word ignores the Space-before formatting of a paragraph style (or just paragraph formatting) when the paragraph is the first one on a page following a page break (or at the top of a column following a column break). You can use a Frame to get around this. The simplest method is to modify the Style:

[image: Modify Style Dialog]

You would want a borderless frame and to have the space-before paragraph formatting that you need.

[image: Paragraph formatting dialog]